# Select same transaction on different months

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select or keep SAME transaction description(TRNDESCR) that only occur at least 3 month using Pandas dataframe. I tried some code  but it does not work as expected.

Given below is the example dataset:

```
    ACNO TIME                   TRNCD   TRNDESCR                                        TRNAMT
0   85   2018-12-19 20:40:00    109     Ib Transfer To Phoutthalom Syh Account No:123   -20000
1   85   2018-12-19 21:15:00    109     Ib Transfer To Phoutthalom Syh Account No:123   -25000
2   85   2018-12-20 15:30:00    109     Ib Transfer To Thongsavath Pra Account No:124   -10000
3   85   2018-12-22 12:30:00    209     Bil Payment                                     -500
4   85   2018-12-25 15:34:00    109     Ib Transfer To Phoutthalom Syh Account No:123   -60000
5   85   2019-01-22 12:30:00    209     Bil Payment                                     -501
6   85   2019-01-23 12:50:00    109     Ib Transfer To Sarah Account No:199             -3000
7   85   2019-01-31 08:59:00    109     Ib Transfer To Thongsavath Pra Account No:124   -650000
8   85   2019-02-02 12:30:00    109     Ib Transfer To Sarah Account No:199             -600
9   85   2019-02-03 15:02:00    109     Ib Transfer To Phoutthalom Syh Account No:123   -60000
10  85   2019-02-04 15:21:00    109     Ib Transfer To Thongsavath Pra Account No:124   -863000
11  85   2019-02-05 15:30:00    209     Bil Payment                                     -600
```

The following is the expected result:

```
    ACNO TIME                   TRNCD   TRNDESCR                                        TRNAMT
0   85   2018-12-20 15:30:00    109     Ib Transfer To Thongsavath Pra Account No:124   -10000
1   85   2018-12-22 12:30:00    209     Bil Payment                                     -500
2   85   2019-01-22 12:30:00    209     Bil Payment                                     -501
3   85   2019-01-31 08:59:00    109     Ib Transfer To Thongsavath Pra Account No:124   -650000
4   85   2019-02-04 15:21:00    109     Ib Transfer To Thongsavath Pra Account No:124   -863000
5   85   2019-02-05 15:30:00    209     Bil Payment                                     -600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select column that is considered as an indicator, like the example you gave, it is TRNDESCR and also TIME as you want put "Month" as the filter. Then you remove duplicate and group by the TRNDESCR, then count how many time the transaction happen based on Month.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['TIME'] = ["2018-12-19", "2018-12-20", "2019-01-20", "2019-02-06",
             "2018-12-18", "2018-12-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-02-06"]
df['TRNDESCR'] = ["ib1", "ib2", "ib2", "ib2",
                 "ib2", "ib3", "ib3", "ib3"]
df['ACNO'] = 85


df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])
df['MONTH'] = df['TIME'].dt.month

count_month = df[['MONTH', 'TRNDESCR']].drop_duplicates(['MONTH', 'TRNDESCR'], keep="last").groupby('TRNDESCR')['MONTH'].count()

df[df['TRNDESCR'].isin(count_month[count_month >= 3].index)]
```

```
TIME    TRNDESCR    ACNO    MONTH
1   2018-12-20  ib2     85  12
2   2019-01-20  ib2     85  1
3   2019-02-06  ib2     85  2
4   2018-12-18  ib2     85  12
5   2018-12-02  ib3     85  12
6   2019-01-03  ib3     85  1
7   2019-02-06  ib3     85  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("df_85.xlsx")

df_copy = df.copy()

# introduce new column
time = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_copy.TIME)
df_copy['yearmonth'] = time.year.astype(str) + time.month.astype(str)

# find month occurences within each TRNDESCR group
new_df = df_copy.groupby(['TRNDESCR']).yearmonth.nunique().to_frame().reset_index()
new_df = new_df[new_df.yearmonth >= 3]

# get row with TRNDESCR matches those in new_df
output_df = df[df.TRNDESCR.isin(new_df.TRNDESCR.values)]

print(output_df)
```

Output

```
    ACNO  YEAR  MONTH                TIME  TRNCD                                       TRNDESCR  TRNAMT
2     85  2018     12 2018-12-20 15:30:00    109  Ib Transfer To Thongsavath Pra Account No:124  -10000
3     85  2018     12 2018-12-22 12:30:00    209                                   Bil Payment     -500
5     85  2018      1 2019-01-22 12:30:00    209                                   Bil Payment     -501
7     85  2019      1 2019-01-31 08:59:00    109  Ib Transfer To Thongsavath Pra Account No:124 -650000
10    85  2019      2 2019-02-04 15:21:00    109  Ib Transfer To Thongsavath Pra Account No:124 -863000
11    85  2019      2 2019-02-05 15:30:00    209                                   Bil Payment     -600
```

It works by creating a new column "yearmonth" (which is a concatenation of year + month). Then it does a groupby to TRNDESCR and count number of unique yearmonth for each group.